# Using JQuery UI Datepicker in Laravel App

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker

I am using Laravel to build an app to manage marketing campaign bookings.

I want use use JQuery Datepicker UI so tghe datepicker can appear in internet exploerer correctly as well as chrome. I am enqueing the datepicker correctly as described in the offcial jquery tutorial:

```
         <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">    

    <!-- FOR DATEPICKER -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/flow_live.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
      } );
    </script>

</head>
```

However, I keep on receiving the error message 'datepicker() is not a function' in the console, and the datepicker does not work, unless I comment out the line
`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`.

When I take this line out, the datepicker works, but I lose a lot of the other functionality attributed to the app, such as the slide down menu in the title bar.

Would anyone be able to suggest a handy way around this?

Perhaps loading the two different scripts at different time intervals?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Did you try adding the `app.css` stylesheet _after_ the `datepicker` stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

why you put those in `head`

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
  } );
</script>
```

please put them in `body` tag
after your implementation for `app.js`

Comment: Hi I have tried this and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using app.js of laravel, you don't need to call JQuery again. app.js includes JQuery. 
Remove

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Datepicker should work now.

Comment: Hi Zahid, that didn't make any difference - it still says 'datepicker is not a function' even when I remove the jquery.min.js and leave the app.js line in my file.